# Running multiple cron jobs from single script

Tags: unix, cron

I have three different jobs that I want to run from the FreeBSD shell. I would like to consolidate them into a single script, if possible, but I can not find any syntax to do that. Is there someway I can accomplish this?

Comment: Why not create a shell script which just calls them all?

Comment: This question needs a lot more information for anybody to be able to help you. What do you mean by "different jobs"? What have you tried? What has failed, and how?

Comment: There are a myriad of was to run multiple "jobs", simplest of all is end the command with a ; then type the next one, etc.

Comment: I apologize for not being descript. I have 3 different commands I want to run at different times. I want to have all three commands be in a single script, but still have cron run them at different times.

Comment: And to add to that, I need to use multiple variables and, from an administrative standpoint, would be much easier handled from a single shell script rather than calling multiples.

Answer (score 3):

you can use article "&" for parallel work and "&&" step-by-step launch script

```
#script.sh & script2.sh & script.sh
```

more info at http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Lists

Comment: You can also run multiple commands by separating them with `;` which will rul all the commands regardless of their return value. `&&` will only continue to run if the previous command was successful.

Answer (score 0):

`crontab` itself runs multiple cronjobs from a single file called `crontab`.

```
0 * * * * /home/username/script.sh
0 * * * * /home/username/script1.sh
0 * * * * /home/username/script2.sh
```